# Parse nested hash keys for permit params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I have hash

```
{
 :home_page=>{
   :hot_products=>{
     :enabled=>true, :always_enable=>false,:order=>0
   },
   :recent_products=>{
     :enabled=>true, :always_enable=>true, :order=>1
   },
   :event_promotion=>{
     :enabled=>true, :always_enable=>false,:order=>2
   }
  }
}
```

And I want permit params using hash keys instead of hard code like this:

```
params.require(:tob).permit home_page: [hot_products: [:enabled, :always_enable]]
```

Do we have any way to get hash key above for permiting the params?

Comment: You mean params[:home_page][:hot_products].permit(:enabled, :always_enable)

Comment: no I mean `arams.require(:tob).permit home_page: [hot_products: [:enabled, :always_enable], recent_products: [:enabled, :always_enable]],...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original Answer

I guess you could just iterate through your parameters hash and extract the keys to build the permitted hash (not tested) :

```
def recursive_hash_keys(hash)
  hash.map do |key, value|
    if value.is_a? Hash
      { key => recursive_hash_keys(value) }
    else
      key
    end
  end
end


def tob_params
  params.require(:tob).permit(
    home_page: recursive_hash_keys(params[:tob][:home_page])
  )
end
```

However, I don't understand why you want to achieve this. The given solution introduces a **SECURITY HOLE**. Permitted parameters shall be hard filtered since this mechanism introduced in Rails 4 is supposed to replace the old *protected attributes* mechanism. Do as you please, but I'm just letting you know that you shouldn't :)

### Edit

To match what you actually want to do (no security issue in this case) :

```
DEFAULT_PARAMS = YAML::load( <<EOY )
home_page:
  hot_products:
    enabled: true 
    always_enable: false
    order: 0
  recent_products:
    enabled: true 
    always_enable: true
    order: 1
  event_promotion:
    enabled: true 
    always_enable: false
    order: 2
EOY

# [...]

def recursive_hash_keys(hash)
  hash.map do |key, value|
    if value.is_a? Hash
      { key => recursive_hash_keys(value) }
    else
      key
    end
  end
end

def tob_params
  DEFAULT_PARAMS.merge(
    params
    .require(:tob)
    .permit(recursive_hash_keys(DEFAULT_PARAMS))
  )
end
```

Althrough, if I'm correctly guessing what you want to do here, I'd suggest  that you do it the "rails's way" :

- Define default values in your [ActiveRecord::Migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) files (deals better with versioning)
- Or else you can define default values in your model using [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)
- And hardcode the permitted parameters in each of your controllers.

Hope this helps, cheers !

Comment: "to replace the old strong parameters mechanism" - huh? This IS the strong parameters. It replaced `attr_accessible`.

Comment: My bad, i meant "protected attributes", long time i didn't code with Rails 3 :) I fixed it.

Comment: Actually, the passing hash is what I have defined in `yaml` file and its default value. And here I want filter params which accept only the param match my configure.

Comment: So, let me get this right : Actually, you just want to define some permitted parameters  (hardcoded) in a `yaml` file and "merge" it with some other incoming parameters and keep the default value from the `yaml` if not defined ?

Answer (score 1):

This could work

1) Get the hash **keys** required

```
params[:home_page].keys
=> [:hot_products, :recent_products, :event_promotion]
```

2) Use the result above to form a hash to permit. Here's one of the ways to do it

```
> params[:home_page].keys.map { |k| {"#{k}": [:enabled, :always_enable]} }
=> [{:hot_products=>[:enabled, :always_enable]},
 {:recent_products=>[:enabled, :always_enable]},
 {:event_promotion=>[:enabled, :always_enable]}]
```

---

**Note**: this weakens the security brought by `strong_parameters`

Comment: the code above is just a sample, and the inner hash might store difference keys

Comment: the method mentioned would work for different keys as well. For example, you can move out the "[:enabled, :always_enable]" part. If I understood your concern correctly